# RewriteRule for images

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have to rewrite some url on my site. I've put this in my htaccess to make this change:
http://example.com/john/?a=1&b=2 --> http://example.com/index.php?account=john&a=1&b=2

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ ./index.php?account=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Now I have to rewrite images url in this way. Every image with this path: **example.com/john/images/a.jpg**

Should point to phisical path: **example.com/accounts/john/images/a.jpg**

How can I do that?

Note: "John" is not fixed but can be every possible word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this script:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?account=$1 [NC,QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/images/([^/]+).jpg$ /accounts/$1/images/$2.jpg [NC,L]
```

Comment: Could you please accept my answer to mark this thread as solved ? [How does accepting an answer works?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)