# How can I preserve spaces (%20) when using Apache RewriteRule?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to setup a rather simple redirect using Apache and .htaccess. In short, I have some image links which contain spaces, for example:

`https://example.com/images/this%20is%20a%20link%20with%20spaces.jpg`

and all I want is to redirect these links to another folder, namely in /wp-content/uploads/ (for a WordPress site), where I have moved the images, therefore I want the link above to redirect to this one:

`https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/this%20is%20a%20link%20with%20spaces.jpg`

Here's what I have in the .htaccess file now:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule "^images\/((.*)\.(.*))$" "/wp-content/uploads/images/$1" [R=301,L]
```

Everything I tried around this rule (including `[NE]`, `[B]`, `[BNP]`), strips all the spaces from the destination, resulting in a redirect to this URL, which is NOT what I want:

`https://example.com/images/thisisalinkwithspaces.jpg`

All the tutorials that I found and followed tell you how to *remove* spaces and none of them tells you how to *preserve* spaces when using Apache, `.htaccess` and `RewriteRule`.

**Later edit**: Here's the output of: `curl -v https://example.com/images/this%20is%20a%20link%20with%20spaces.jpg`

```
> GET /images/this%20is%20a%20link%20with%20spaces.jpg HTTP/1.1
> Host: example.com
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Date: Mon, 29 Apr 2019 21:17:14 GMT
< Server: Apache
< Expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
< Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
< X-Redirect-By: WordPress
< Location: https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/images/thisisalinkwithspaces.jpg
< Content-Length: 0
* Connection #0 to host example.com left intact
```

And here's the complete `.htaccess` file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule "^images\/((.*)\.(.*))$" "/wp-content/uploads/images/$1" [R=301,L]
```

Any help with this would be much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: There's nothing in your rewrite url that would strip spaces. The 301 is a permanent redirect. Try testing in another browser or in incognito. If you're still running into the issue, chances are you have another set of RewriteRules conflicting somewhere.

Comment: Might also try testing outside of wordpress with a different file name to help isolate the issue. It shouldn't be stripping spaces.

Comment: Thanks @Ultimater, unfortunately, it doesn't work in incognito and not even in other browsers. There is nothing else in my .htaccess file except the standard WordPress block of rules. And I tried placing the rule above both inside the WordPress set of rules and outside of it, to no avail :-(

Comment: As @Ultimater said, your apache redirect rule is not stripping the spaces. What is the output of `curl -v https://example.com/images/this%20is%20a%20link%20with%20spaces.jpg`?

Comment: Thanks @DusanBajic, I added the response in the question body, as it wouldn't fit here properly. It's intriguing that the redirect is generated by WordPress, therefore I'll consult the rewrite rules from WordPress and write back here.

Comment: Does your JPG file actually exist with the spaces? Otherwise the rewrite rule will boot up the wordpress PHP codebase to figure out what to do with the image request due to a 404 encountered. What if you use `+` instead of `%20` in the url? Also please use a 302 redirect while debugging. Try adding a querystring to the URL while debugging in your browser to get around the cached 301 redirect in your browser and/or clear your browsers cached 301 redirect. If you're using chrome, you can also follow the request in your browser with the network tab.

Comment: Finally, make sure you're ordering your rewrite rules correctly. You need your custom rewrite BEFORE wordpress serves it as a 404 to PHP as the last rule.
Move your custom RewriteRule to directly under `RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]` but before the RewriteCond.

Comment: Just noticed you answered your own question with a solution. Please accept your own answer so others know this is answered.

Answer (score 1):

You might try [this RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/M6DlQt/1) in your RewriteRule. You might change this URL:

```
^https:\/\/example\.com\/images\/this(.*)$
```

to

```
 https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/this$1
```

and it might work.

[image]

If you only want to do that single image, you might only use <kbd>\</kbd> char and escape metachars such as <kbd>%</kbd>, and you may not need any specific regex. You can simply do that by redirecting:

```
^https:\/\/example\.com\/images\/this\%20is\%20a\%20link\%20with\%20spaces\.jpg$
```

to

```
https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/this\%20is\%20a\%20link\%20with\%20spaces\.jpg
```

You might need to clear your browser cache, restart your apache.

#### htaccess

Your rule may look like this. You may read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35019134/6553328) to make sure:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^https:\/\/example\.com\/images\/this(.*)$ https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/this$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Thanks @Emma, that unfortunately doesn't work, despite the fact that the online REGEX checkers do validate this rule. And it's not a single image, as that would've been easy to fix. I believe there is some setting in Apache that simply removes all the spaces from the link and I don't know how to make it keep the full URL, with spaces. I've also added the rule I'm using, as I forgot to put it in the initial question. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I managed to finally figure it out! This was all due to a WordPress plugin that I tried to use before adding the redirects in `.htaccess`. It seems to be some sort of bug in that plugin, which probably escapes the URL's and results in stripping down the spaces in the file names. The final `.htaccess` file to achieve a fully working solution, was this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Redirect old images to their new location in /wp-content/uploads/
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ /wp-content/uploads/images/$1 [R=301,L]

# Rest of standard WordPress rules
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Thank you all for your hints and guidance!